# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo') Next13js typescript

Tags: typescript, next.js, react-hooks

I am currently working on a Next.js 13 project with TypeScript where I am using the useDrag hook. While I am not receiving any errors in my Visual Studio Code editor, I am encountering an error message when attempting to render the page. The error message indicates that there is a problem with the useMemo function and that it cannot read properties of null.

Server Error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')
This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
```

this is the source code

```
import { useDrag } from 'react-dnd';
import { ItemType } from './../types/ItemType';
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';



interface HeaderProps {
  width: number;
  height: number;
  background: string;
}

const Header = ({ width, height, background }: HeaderProps) => {
  const [drag, dragRef] = useMemo(() => {
    return useDrag(() => ({
      type: ItemType.HEADER,
      item: { width, height, background },
      collect: (monitor) => ({
        isDragging: !!monitor.isDragging(),
      }),
    }), [width, height, background]);
  }, [width, height, background]);

  const isDragging = drag?.isDragging as boolean;

  return (
    <div
      ref={dragRef}
      style={{
        width,
        height,
        background,
        opacity: isDragging ? 0.5 : 1,
        cursor: 'move',
      }}
    />
  );
};

export const SideMenu = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: '300px', background: '#f8f8f8' }}>
      <Header width={200} height={50} background="blue" />
    </div>
  );
};
```

what i missing? or what its wrong here?

Comment: did you figure this out? I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you do

> npm install anything

You are in your working repository, so it can add dependencies into your files.